# yii: textfieldrow always has the default value and background,but I dont want it

Tags: php, yii, textfield, jpasswordfield

Here is a `textFieldRow` before the `passwordField`,the `textFieldRow` always has the same background color as the `passwordField`,and always has the default value. I want a white blank `textField` but I can't. I've try to set the blank value and white background color to it,and it seems not worked, maybe it was covered by yii itself.

If some direction toward the right solution, that would be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a CSS issue?

Comment: It seems like...but what can I do to the default value about the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the css of your corresponding theme.If you haven't customized the theme,you can check the `css\form.css` of your application. You can edit the css corresponds to text field in your form there.

Set default value like

```
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array( 'placeholder'=>'Enter your Name')); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks,but I still have no idea about the default value about the textfield before the passwordfield.

Comment: You can set the default value by setting the place holder property.

Comment: I'v tried your direction,but it didn't work.Thanks all the same.